# Find an integral $\int{\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, fractions

$$\int{\frac{dx}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}}$$

To solve this indefinite integral, I use fraction expansion and I get a wrong system of equations:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
B = 0 \\ 
A + 2B + C = 0 \\ 
A + B + C = 1
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

What is the problem with my fraction expansion?

Comment: You want something in the form $\frac{ax+b}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{cx+d}{x^2+1}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. The polynomial at the denominator is of degree $4$ and you have three parameters. Try with is the following [partial fraction decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition) (with  four parameters):
$$\frac{1}{(x+1)^2(x^2+1)}=\frac{Ax+B}{x^2+1}+\frac{C}{x+1}+\frac{D}{(x+1)^2}.$$